# How to set time limit for inputting information to console?

Tags: java, concurrency, console

Programm should have conversation with user in console (Eclipse IDE), if user have no ansver to question during some time (10 sec. for example), which programm ask in console, programm should ask next one.

How to close input in console if the user has not entered anything?
Example of executing:

```
programm print: "What is your name?"
user can put: "Bond"
programm print: "How old are you?"
user can put: "25"
```

(in this case everything is good)

But l have problem with such situation:

```
programm print: "What is your name?"
user put anything
programm print: "How old are you?"
user can put: "25"
```

and after that console ia active and l can put one line. If user will ignore 100 question for example, console will provide putting 100 line, how to solve this problem?

My code look like:

```
 ...
 static answer;
 ...

 // 5 questions for example
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(System.in));

     final Thread timeForAnswer = new Thread(() -> {
         Thread.sleep(10000);
     }).start();

     final Thread input = new Thread(() -> {
         answer = reader.readLine();
        // If user put answer before 10 sec. period - interrupt timeForAnswer and ask next question
        timeForAnswer.interrupt();
     }).start();

     timeForAnswer.join();

     input.interrupt();

     System.out.println("Answer: " + answer);
```

}

Comment: Have a look at Future and its `get` with timeout.

Comment: See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Comment: @Fildor Can you get example of inputting with Future?

Comment: Wrap your "input" thread code in a Callable and submit it to an ExecutorService. You'll get back a Future. On that future you can call get with timeout. That will block until there is a result to return or time is up.

Comment: Maybe also a completablefuture would be the way to go: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html#completablefutures